# Quadcopter return to home function not working

Tags: quadcopters, return-to-home

I have a small S49 quadcopter. Whenever I am flying it and initiate *Return to Home* on the controller, it always returns to the wrong location compared to where it launched from. Sometimes maybe 5/10 metres away. How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Having Googled the S49 drone, it appears that your drone uses ‘headless rth’.

This means that instead of using GPS, the drone goes into ‘headless mode’ then pitches backwards towards you.

Unfortunately, due to the nature of how this works and the inaccuracies of the accelerometer, this process is rarely accurate.

I don’t know of any way to fix this as it is a hardware limitation as far as I know, so I suggest you think of it more as a way to move the drone roughly towards yourself to recover it if you lose orientation, rather than a way to have the drone return and land accurately.